# How to get an array of months in c#

Tags: c#

I want to get the month array in c#.
somthing like this : `{ January , February , ... , December }`
How can I do this? please send me codes in C#.
thanks

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You need to careful about localization issues as well:
You can use:

```
string[] monthNames = 
    System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture
        .DateTimeFormat.MonthGenitiveNames;
```

The genitive case is introduced in some inflected languages by a genitive noun inflection, which in non-inflected languages matches the use of the equivalent of the English preposition "of". For example, a date in the Russian (Russia), "ru-RU", culture, consists of the day number and the genitive month name.

[More info…](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.monthgenitivenames.aspx)

**EDIT**: If you need english month names you can set your current culture as `en-US`

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
```

Comment: how can I get just english months?

Comment: You need to set your current culture as en-US
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
and then use
tring[] monthNames = 
  System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.MonthGenitiveNames;

This will ensure that code is localization ready

Comment: Changing the current culture would affect all further execution on that thread. Would probably be a good idea to read the original value and change it back after your code. Or you could you call something like new CultureInfo("...").DateTimeFormat.MonthGenitiveNames.

Comment: Note that this returns a 13th, blank month name.

Comment: The `InvariantCulture` returns the English month names so no need to set the thread culture for those

Answer (score 17):

```
string[] monthNames = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.MonthNames;

foreach (string m in monthNames) // writing out
{
    Console.WriteLine(m);
}
```

**Output:**

```
January
February
March
April
May
June
July
August
September
October
November
December
```

**Update:**
Do note that for different locales/cultures, the output might not be in English. Haven't tested that before though.

For US English only:

```
string[] monthNames = (new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US")).DateTimeFormat.MonthNames;
```

Comment: Hi
You need to be careful about teh use of MonthNames insome languages like russian, look at my post below

Comment: Ngm's `MonthGenitiveNames` method could be more suitable depending on the context.

Comment: OK, I've added "`en-US` cultureinfo" Month Names

Comment: This gives an array of length 13, not 12, where the last element is blank. My gut reaction is that this is not desirable.

Answer (score 12):

```
string[] months = new string[] {"January", "February", "March", "April", "May",
  "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"};
```

Comment: Yeah, what's wrong with writing what you mean?  Kudos for remembering how to KISS.

Comment: And you don't even need `new string[] {`, `new [] {` will do.

Answer (score 8):

An alternate that hopefully teaches how you can apply the range function to create for sequential things.

```
var startDate = new DateTime(2014,1,1);
var months = Enumerable.Range(0,11)
                       .Select(startDate.AddMonths);
                       .Select(m => m.ToString("yyyy MMMM"))
                       .ToList();
```

What it is doing is creating a DateTime object (startDate) and using that object to generate all the other dates relative to itself.

1. Enumerable.Range(0,11) creates a list of integers {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11}
2. Select(startDate.AddMonths) feeds each of those integers to the AddMonths function of startDate which produces a list of dates from January to December.
3. Select(m => m.ToString("yyyy MMMM") takes each of the dates from january to december and converts them into a formatted string (in this case "2014 January")
4. ToList() evaluates all the functions and returns it as a list of strings.

Comment: not the best way of getting month names, but definitely great as an alternative solution. +1 for the good effort and explanation.